# Store user ID on wp_term_taxonomy when new term inserted

Tags: hooks, terms

I've added a new column called `term_author` to the `wp_terms` table to store which user is inserting each term.

Before a term is inserted, I've added a filter to insert the user ID, but although I'm successfully intercepting before insertion, I'm getting this error upon insert:

```
PHP Warning:  Attempt to assign property 'term_author' of non-object
```

My code:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_term_data', function ($data, $taxonomy, $args) {

    $userId = get_current_user_id();
    $data->{"term_author"} = $userId;
    return $data;

}, 10, 3);
```

I think I might need to register the new column with the WP engine to allow it to store the user ID, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to alter core tables - you could've instead stored the author as a term meta.. And as for the error in question, that's because [`$data` is an array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_term_data/)..

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you, I will try storing author as term meta, that makes much more sense

Comment: @SallyCJ is there a hook to get term ID after insertion so I can store author on term meta? Not sure the best place to do this (I'm very new to WP dev), thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the appropriate hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/ , thank you for the help on best practices

Comment: Sorry I had something to do, but yes, that's one of the hook that you can use, but if you want to know whether the term is being created or updated, you'd want to use the [`saved_<taxonomy>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/saved_taxonomy/) instead.

Comment: Great thank you, that's even more helpful